# How to Add input fields in form when "Other" option is selected in dropdown in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have a multi select dropdown input and I am saving all the selected items in an (useState) array when user click add icon.

I want to render input field when "Other" option is selected in dropdown.
and also want that the value entered in other should be added in the array.

handle change :-

```
const handleCareerChoice = (event) => {
setValues({ ...values, careerChoice: event.target.value });
}; 

const handleChange = (input) => (event) => {
setValues({ ...values, error: false, [input]:event.target.value});
};

 const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState(false);
```

dropdown

```
 <Grid container className={classes.grid} style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}>
<Grid item xs={11} sm={5} lg={11} sx={{ m: 1 }}>
  <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label">
      Top Career Choice
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
      label="Top Career Choice"
      id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      value={values.careerChoice}
      onChange={handleChange("careerChoice")}
      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
    >
      <TextField variant="outlined" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
      {careerChoice.map((name) => (
        <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
          <Checkbox checked={values.careerChoice.indexOf(name) > -1} />
          <ListItemText primary={name} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
        <MenuItem >
          <Checkbox onClick={setOtherCareerChoice(!otherCareerChoice)} />
          <ListItemText primary={"Others"} />
        </MenuItem>
    </Select>

  </FormControl>
   
</Grid>

{ otherCareerChoice  && (
<Grid item xs={11} sm={5} lg={11} sx={{ m: 1 }}>
          <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password">
   Other Career Choice
    </InputLabel>
    <OutlinedInput
      id="careerChoice"
      name="careerChoice"
      label="Additional Career Choice"
      fullWidth
      autoComplete="careerChoice"
      // value={values.careerChoice}
      onChange={handleCareerChoice}
                    endAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <IconButton
                    edge="end"
                  >
                  <Add/>
                  </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
              }
    />
  </FormControl>
</Grid>
)}
```

currently, input is looking like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARWGW.png) but on clicking other text field, I see a blank screen with error
`TypeError: selected.join is not a function`
Please suggest me a good approach to do this

Comment: Please attach your entire code, we cannot replicate your situation with this incomplete code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: selected.join not being a function is because selected is not an array. Try log selected at that point and see.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-wave-64e9x?file=/src/App.js
here is the link to full code on codesandbox

Comment: You want the flow to be something like this right? User selects "Others" in first box -> Second box gets rendered -> User types something in second box and clicks "+" -> This new text is now shown in the first box

Comment: yes exactly!! @PHRYTE

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-galois-2mpqm?file=/src/App.js:2782-3236) for the full code

First you want to render the "Other Career Text" input box when it is selected from the dropdown. For that, add an `onClick` for Others in the dropdown

```
<MenuItem onClick={() => setOtherCareerChoice(!otherCareerChoice)}>
  <Checkbox />
  <ListItemText primary={"Others"} />
</MenuItem>
```

Now that the input field is rendered, at a value and onChange attribute to let the user type a text

```
<OutlinedInput
  value={otherCareerText}
  onChange={(event) => setOtherCareerText(event.target.value)}
```

Finally when the user clicks the "+" button, push this text to your state in an `onClick`

```
<IconButton
  onClick={() => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      careerChoice: [...values.careerChoice, otherCareerText]
    });
    setOtherCareerChoice(false);
    setOtherCareerText("");
  }}
 >
```